# Diagonalization of a hermitian matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The given matrix is:

\begin{bmatrix}1&i&2+i\\-i&2&1-i\\ 2-i&1+i&2\end{bmatrix}

I calculated the eigenvalues and then felt lazy to calculate the eigenvalues by hand. So I tried wolframalpha. This is the result I got:

[image: Diagonalized matrix]

I have two questions related to it:

1. Shouldn't $S^{-1}=S^T$ here, as $M$ is a hermitian matrix?
2. Is there a better way to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors by hand for a hermitian matrix?

[The wolframalpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize%20%7B%7B1,i,2%2Bi%7D,%7B-i,2,1-i%7D,%7B2-i,1%2Bi,2%7D%7D)

Comment: Well, you told Wolfie A to diagonalise the matrix, but you didn't tell it to diagonalise it by a Hermitian (or unitary) matrix.

Comment: I did not think of that. I just realized my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding question 1: no.  All we know is that (because the eigenvalues of $M$ are distinct) if we normalize the columns of $S$, then the *resulting* matrix is unitary.  By the way, a unitary matrix satisfies $U^{-1} = \overline{U^T}$ as opposed to $U^{-1} = U^T$.

Regarding question 2: also no.  If you want the exact eigenvalues, you have to go through the same process. There are neat methods of approximating the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix, though.

Comment: What about eigenvectors? Do we need to solve a system of linear equations corresponding to each eigenvalue? Or is there a neater method?